# Why doesn't MSVC give out an error when using function calls in __assume?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

When I use `__assume(SomeFunc());` it compiles fine, even though `__assume` is supposed to be a compile-time hint and `SomeFunc()` can not have its return value predicted at compile time.

Could someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `SomeFunc()` cannot have its return value predicted at compile time.

The compiler may not be able to compute the return value at compile time, but that doesn't matter.

When you use [`__assume(expression)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b3fsfxw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), *you*, the programmer, are telling the compiler "this expression always evaluates to `true`."  You are giving the compiler extra information that it might not otherwise be able to deduce from the source code.

If the expression happens not to evaluate to `true` when it is evaluated at run time, then the behavior is undefined.  It is your responsibility to use `__assume` only where the expression is guaranteed to be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Often functions can have their return values predicted at compile time. And even if one can't, why should `__assume` fail to compile? It's a hint to the optimizer. If it's not a useful hint, it won't do anything useful, but there's no reason for it to fail.

Note also that the documentation for `__assume` suggests using it for assertions in release mode. But function calls are often used in assertions. If `__assume` wasn't allowed to take function return values, you'd need two different assert macros.